# how to on click textarea focus with chips input Vue CSS

Tags: css

I want to have onclick focus for the entire area(chip-container), and currently I give focus to the chip-container class, but I don't have any change when the text is clicked. I think because that I also have an input is difference from the chip-container, I would like to have the chip-container as a textarea, but I can't just use textarea attribute because it won't take my chips behaviour.

My question is how can I give proper class to chip-container, input or other div so I can have the entire area onclick to focus.

Here is code for template

```
<div class="chip-container">
      <div class="chip" v-for="(chip, i) of chips" :key="chip.label">
        {{chip}}
        <i class="material-icons" @click="deleteChip(i)">clear</i>
      </div>
      <input v-model="currentInput" @keypress.enter="saveChip" @keydown.delete="backspaceDelete">
    </div>
```

Here is CSS

```
.chip-container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 167px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  min-height: 34px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
  .chip {
    margin:4px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    padding:0px 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc
    border-radius: 3px;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    i {
      cursor: pointer;
      opacity: .56;
      margin-left:8px;
    }
  }
  input {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    width:30px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding:4px;
&:focus {
    border-color: bule;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 2px blue, 0.5;
    outline: 0;
  }
  }
}
```

here is live code:https://codepen.io/lydchair/pen/ExKLqpK

the entire container should be able to focus when click, not just the input area, should be like this[image: before make the text chip]

[image]

both pic are showing in the same area, just before and after text become chips

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, This may help you to solve your problem.
To focus for input field you can use :focus pseudo-class.
The :focus CSS pseudo-class represents an element (such as a form input) that has received focus. It is generally triggered when the user clicks or taps on an element or selects it with the keyboard's Tab key.
Refer more about pseudo-classes on this link.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        .chip-container {
            display:flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            align-content: space-between;
            width: 300px;
        }
        input{
            width: 100%;
            transition-duration: 500ms;
        }
        input:focus{
            transition-duration: 500ms;
            background-color: #d1d9e0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="chip-container">
    <label for="in">Chips</label>
    <input id="in"></input>
</div>

<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HI, I understand how to focus the input area, that's not quite my problem, my problem is that I want to focus the entire chip-container, as the second pic, the area also shows the chips, so it's not just an input